# MVPVM - Event handling using Interface or Presenter

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, mvvm, mvp

Handling button click, row double click and other events. What is a better approach?

Direct Access of presenter to View. So the view can directly call the appropriate method on the presenter, eg. `Presenter.Save()`

**Or**

Event in interface.

```
interface ILoginDetailView:
{
   event EventHandler Save;        
}
```

View

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Save(this, null)
}
```

Presenter

```
view.Save += new EventHandler(view_Save);
```

I feel the 2nd approach is better as it makes the view decoupled from the presenter. But in all the articles/papers where the pattern is described, 1st approach is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first approach is much cleaner.

A *Save* just doesn't feel like an *event*. It's a direct action.

In MVVM you're calling a command on the viewmodel, in MVC you're calling an action on a controller and in MVP you're calling a method on the presenter.

A *Saved* or *Saving* is an event, but not *Save*.

But it's probably a question about personal preferences.

Comment: That's just semantics... he could have called it view.SaveButtonClicked... what would your answer be then?

Comment: yes, and he could have called it DoSomething. But it doesn't matter because the question was about if he should use an event or a presenter method.

Comment: Testability, as per the other posts. I just think it's cleaner to have interfaces you can mock. TDD and all that... Hard-binding views feels like a cheap way out to me. You now have a View that is not just a dumb view any more.

Comment: @Heliac please read the comments at the post by Spontifixus. What's your problem with testability? Really, the presenter have an IView interface in both. Why do you think it's easier to test an event subscribing than a method call? I did a lot of work in TDD+MVP and the testing is not different in these cases, the event variation is just an extra step giving false impressions about the coupling without extra value.

Comment: I've discussed this with some of my friends. TDD was maybe not the best approach in this debate. Like you said, both methods require the same amount of work for test logic. But what about the advantages you gain from loose-coupling, and what if you want to swap in different Views? Is it not good practice to try and make life easier for the programmers who will be adding to your code later on?

Comment: That is what I say. The evented model is a bit more loose-coupled but the view-knows-the-presenter approach is cleaner and the loose-coupling is good enough here, you don't gain too much additional, real value from the evented approach. Please read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648280.aspx and you will realize that this is mainly about personal preferences, that's why I start with "I think".

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I always go for the second approach. Generally, I don't like having the view know about the presenter, and the decoupling is a great advantage. Otherwise, I find myself making functions taking specific variables from the view. The event pattern breaks that nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I also would go with the second approach, because as you stated that decouples the view from the presenter, which in turn makes that stuff testable.

Comment: "which in turn makes that stuff testable" how is the second approach gives you more testability?

Comment: @PeterPorfy you can create a mock-up for the `ILoginDetailView` and thus there's no need to really instantiate a view. Rather the mock-up could behave exactly as you want it to to test your ViewModel.

Comment: Neither when you use the first approach.

Comment: I see no difference in testing when I call the Save method on my presenter or I trigger an event from my mock view. The second one is a bit more work and no value added.

Comment: @PeterPorfy You are right when the sole purpose of this interface is to provide access to the View's events. When using the interface additionally to access other parts from the View (for whatever reasons) that would make testing of that parts easier...

Comment: both approach takes an interface of the view, this is mvp. This is why I was asking why is the second one gives you more testability?

Comment: You are right when talking about MVP. I was of the opinion that we were talking about MVVM, as the question is tagged as that. I have re-tagged it as MVP.

Answer (score 2):

In the MVPVM (model view presenter view model) pattern it's stated that the view is usually tightly coupled to your view.  This allows your view-model, view, and business/data access layers to remain decoupled.

So once again, the presenter can be tightly to allow direct access to the view without adding responsibility to your view model or view.

[MVPVM Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580734.aspx)

It's a great article and discusses MVC, MVP, MVVM, and MVPVM verly well.